# Why are my SSD operations extremely slow every "first time"?

Tags: lubuntu, ssd

Using Lubuntu 20.04, when I perform a read operation with a couple of relatively large files on my SSD (approximately 700 MB in total), it takes a painfully long time. For example, I observe this when calculating the MD5 checksums for all those files using the `md5sum` tool. That operation requires several minutes and `iotop` reports a disk read around 4 M/s (which is extremely slow).

The strange thing is: when I repeat the exact same operation, then again it takes that long, but the third or fourth time (or sometimes right in between), the command completes in a jiffy (too fast for `iotop` to report anything). That does not only happen with checksum calculation but also for other operations (such as concatenating the files).

I read something about *I/O buffering*, but I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with this issue. Does anybody have an idea what's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The faster *reads* will likely be because the drive data is cached in RAM, thus no disk reads are necessary. Lubuntu 20.04 LTS being a LTS release of Ubuntu, provides the choice of multiple kernel stacks (GA, HWE & possible OEM for your machine); with Lubuntu the installation media  dictates which kernel stack you're opting using (*unless changed post-install, or you switched to a OEM kernel that Lubuntu doesn't provide on their installation ISOs*) which you didn't specify, with some hardware performs better on a different stack; so you may get better by changing stack (may get no change too)

Comment: Have you partitioned your SSD before using it? ... Using SSD / HDD without partitioning it first (at least one partition) can result in low read / write speeds.

Comment: Yes, the SSD is partitioned with a partition alignment of 1 MB. But the hdparm tool reports a disk reading speed between 3 MB/sec and 4 MB/sec (which is ridiculous). The SDD worked flawlessly a couple of weeks ago. Now, my primary question is whether I am experiencing hardware failure or a software error here. I also wonder why the RAM caching does not already kick in for the second reading attempt, but only during the third time. Isn't that strange? Yesterday, I tested the SDD from a Lubuntu live DVD and the results were the same.